# Include a png/svg inside a polygon?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to think of the best way to include an image inside an SVG polygon element, like the below:

```html
<svg id="graph" width="100%" height="400px">
  <!-- pattern -->
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%"
             viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <image x="0%" y="0%" width="64" height="64" xlink:href="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/imod/512/Software/labo.png"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <polygon stroke="red" stroke-width="2px" fill="url(#image)" points="300,150 225,280 75,280 0,150 75,20 225,20"></polygon>
</svg>
```

However, i also want to fill the `polygon` with a background colour `fill`, but as this is using the above pattern i'm not sure of the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `polygon` into your `defs`, but take the `fill` out. Then make two copies with the `use` tag, the back one filled with your color and the front one filled with your image. You can also make multiple copies by including more images, changing the coordinates, etc.

```html
<svg id="graph" width="100%" height="400px">
  <!-- pattern -->
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image1" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <image x="0%" y="0%" width="64" height="64" xlink:href="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/imod/512/Software/labo.png"></image>
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="image2" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <image x="0%" y="0%" width="64" height="64" xlink:href="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/imod/512/Software/iPhoto.png"></image>
    </pattern>
    <polygon id="myShape" stroke="red" stroke-width="2px" points="300,150 225,280 75,280 0,150 75,20 225,20"></polygon>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#myShape" fill="yellow"/>
  <use xlink:href="#myShape" fill="url(#image1)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#myShape" fill="orange" x="400"/>
  <use xlink:href="#myShape" fill="url(#image2)" x="400"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hey there. Would this approach work for multiple polygons, with multiple different images defined?

Comment: Does my update address your question? I added a second shape with a different image and different background colour, but still using the same original `polygon` in the `defs`.

Comment: Looks good! Thanks for that Andrew. Out of interest, can you easily control the size of the <image> inside the <polygon> at all? i.e. to make it smaller and centered.

Comment: You can, e.g. in your original example in the `pattern` element, change the `viewBox` value from `0 0 64 64` to `0 0 128 128` and then to `-32 -32 128 128` to see some ways to do this. However, I don't think you can use the same pattern-based-on-an-image with different sizes/placements in different `use` elements. You would have to duplicate the `pattern` element itself and change its presentation attributes.